# Why does my Xubuntu LibreOffice look ugly?

Tags: xubuntu, libreoffice, appearance

My LibreOffice installation looks like Windows 95. The rest of my Xubuntu looks okay. Why? How can I fix it?

[image: current Libreoffice looks]

<sup>Click on the image for a full-resolution picture.</sup>

On the screenshot Leafpad and Calculator are open for comparison.

[image: Libreoffice Xubuntu dialog window]

<sup>Click on the image for a full-resolution picture.</sup>

[image: Libreoffice Xubuntu main screen]

<sup>Click on the image for a full-resolution picture.</sup>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By investigating with Synaptic and trial & error method I came up with the solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-gtk3
```

I have no idea why these packages were missing. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Tango installed well, but didn't help. Gtk and gtk3 styles were not found in repository. I also found a "human" style, which changed nothing.

Comment: `libreoffice-gtk3` and `libreoffice-gtk` are from standard quantal repositories. You have to have them. I had typos in their names, @chaskes corrected it.

Comment: To Gentoo users: You need the `gtk` USE flag on when building `app-office/libreoffice` (or, don't explicitly have it `-gtk` in your `make.conf`, for example).

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends libreoffice-gtk3
```

Just install what is needed to **make your LibreOffice beautiful again**.

Works on (X|L)Ubuntu 18.04+.

Comment: Years later this is also needed on Ubuntu MATE 22.04 (at least if you're not using Snap).

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk
```

Also upper command line works for lubuntu (LXDE).
For example with flat gtk theme 'victory' and 'papirus' icons LibreOffice looks great.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum requirements to get the correct look for LibreOffice in Xubuntu is `libreoffice-gtk` along with *either* `libreoffice-style-tango` *or* `libreoffice-style-human`

Comment: As of 2015 on Mint/Cinnamon, only libreoffice-gtk was needed. Human style is apparently built-in.