# Libreoffice looks ugly after installing wine

Tags: wine, libreoffice

After installing wine(i think) my LibreOffice  writer got a windows look.

How can I set the theme back to default?

I tried rebooting my computer, reinstalling LibreOffice and removing wine.

[image]

Edit:

After running the command from this thread: 
[Why does my Xubuntu LibreOffice look ugly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285089/why-does-my-xubuntu-libreoffice-look-ugly?rq=1)

It's really messed up now.

[image: img]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Can you add the screenshot in the actual post?

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: Do you know how to add it to the post? Or should I show you?

Comment: Did you reboot? Or at least restart LO?

Comment: Askubuntu only allows me to post a link. I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Installing Wine cannot possibly have any influence in native software.

Comment: I tried reinstalling it.

Comment: @ruttydm - I edited your post to embed the image.

Comment: Ok this is becoming a better question. Can you specify what you tried to fix the issue? Also can you make the title an actual question?

Comment: Can you try to `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style-human` and then go into LO settings and choose the human style as theme.